# Get content inside HTML tags with RegExp

Tags: php, regex, match

I'd like to extract the content from a large file of table cells using regexp and process the data using PHP.

Here's the data I would like to match:

```
<td>Current Value: </td><td>100.178</td>
```

I tried using this regexp to match and retrieve the text:

```
preg_match("<td>Current Value: </td><td>(.+?)</td>", $data, $output);
```

However I get an "Unknown modifier" warning and my variable $output comes out empty.

How can I accomplish this - and could you give me a brief summary of how the solution works so I can try to understand why my code didn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add delimiters around your regex:

```
preg_match("#<td>Current Value: </td><td>(.+?)</td>#", $data, $output);
```

The standard delimiter is `/`, but you can use other non-alphanumeric characters if you wish (which makes sense here because the regex itself contains slashes). In your case, the regex engine thought you wanted to use angle brackets as delimiters - and failed.

One more tip (aside from the canonical exhortation "Thou shalt not parse HTML with regexen" (which I think is perfectly OK in a specific case like this)): Use `([^<>]+)` instead of `(.*?)`. This ensures that your regex will never travel across nested tags, a common source of errors when dealing with markup languages.

Comment: This worked. When are delimiters necessary? Can they be any character?

Comment: They are always necessary (in PHP), and they can be any non-alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a DOM Parser.  It will make your life a lot easier, keep your code cleaner, and will be easier to maintain.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

This has some examples of accessing child elements:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_traverse

Comment: This is a little above what I need for this particular project, but this looks like a beautiful library. I'm sure I'll be using it in the future!

Comment: @Marathon it's not. In fact, it's a piece of crap (sorry @jmort, it really is. nothing personal). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662 for better alternatives.

Comment: @Gordon - LOL no worries.  String parsing really isn't much better either.  I didn't know that's what SimpleXML was all about.  How disgusting.