# How would I get the text within an HTML element in PHP?

Tags: html

I've only just started learning PHP, and I can't figure how to get the text from a HTML element.

Here's my HTML code (I'm making a web text editor):

```
<div id="example-one" contenteditable="true">
    <style scoped>
        #example-one { margin-bottom: 10px; }
        [contenteditable="true"] { padding: 10px; outline: 2px dashed #CCC; }
  [  contenteditable="true"]:hover { outline: 2px dashed #0090D2; }
</style>
<p>Everything contained within this div is editable in a browser that supports <code>HTML5</code>. Go on, give it a try: click it and start typing.</p>
</div>
```

Can you guys please explain how I'd get the text of the paragraph element, or the div element?

Thanks for listening!
-Sam

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to get the value of the text in the HTML element and use it within PHP.

This doesn't really make sense, as PHP is a server-side language, and HTML is what the client will see. This is really good actually, as it allows you to generate HTML within PHP, interspersing the PHP with HTML to get what you want.

Example:

```
<form method="post" action"">
    <input name="someInputThatsAlwaysHere" />
    <?php
    //Now this is PHP, so we can have some fun, like having control statements:
    if($condition === true) {
    ?>
    <input name="isOnlyHereIfConditionIsTrue" />
    <?php } else { ?>
    <input name="isOnlyHereifConditionIsFalse" />
    <?php } ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this markup passed up to the server?  If so there's an example for doing this that might help located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688691/get-content-inside-html-tags-with-regexp) if your comfortable with regular expressions.  Otherwise, you can go the way of strings and use string splitting found in the [PHP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688691/get-content-inside-html-tags-with-regexp) to grab the inner content.

If you're on the client-side you won't be using PHP, but JavaScript.  If you're using jQuery you could access the id of the div or paragraph tag by doing something like:

```
var content = $("#example-one").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

one method:

```
<?php echo'<div id="example-one" contenteditable="true">
    <style scoped> 
        #example-one { margin-bottom: 10px; }    
        [contenteditable="true"] { padding: 10px; outline: 2px dashed #CCC; }  
         [  contenteditable="true"]:hover { outline: 2px dashed #0090D2; }  
     </style>
     <p>Everything contained within this div is editable in a browser that supports<code>HTML5</code>. Go on, give it a try: click it and start typing.</p>
  </div>';
?>
```

another method:

```
<?php

$html = '<div id="example-one" contenteditable="true">
    <style scoped>
        #example-one { margin-bottom: 10px; }
        [contenteditable="true"] { padding: 10px; outline: 2px dashed #CCC; }
        [  contenteditable="true"]:hover { outline: 2px dashed #0090D2; }
    </style>
    <p>Everything contained within this div is editable in a browser that supports <code>HTML5</code>. Go on, give it a try: click it and start typing.</p>
    </div>';
$content = getTextBetweenTags('html', $html, 1);
foreach( $content as $item )
{
    echo $item.'<br />';
}

?>
```